# Countif with two ''if'' functions

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm struggling to find a solution to this problem.

I've got a list of teams with their closed and open tickets. Each team also has a solution to their ticket listed in column C. Every time I count how many tickets does each team have it includes the closed tickets as well. How do I count only the open tickets.

For example I'd like to know if ticket status is open, how many of 'bucket' tickets team EE8 has.

[image: table example]

Comment: You can use [COUNTIFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) It allows the use of more than one criteria.

Comment: ...or insert [**Pivot Table**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576) - in this case, you will immediately see all open / closed tickets and their number for each of the solutions for each teams

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Countifs function or Sumproduct function.

1. Please copy column A to other blank cells.
   Choose this new column, go to Data tab > Data Tools > Remove Duplicates.

[image]

2. Enter the formula `=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$16,E2,$B$2:$B$16,"Open",$C$2:$C$16,"Bucket")` or `=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$16=E2)*($B$2:$B$16="Open")*($C$2:$C$16="Bucket"))`.
   Then you can get the open tickets with "Bucket" for each teams.

[image]
[image]